GitLab issue connection
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/anchor/anchor-ui/.git/
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlabnew.techwave.net/anchor/anchor-ui.git/': Could not resolve host: gitlabnew.techwave.net
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:02
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
try to connect to gitlab fetching issues were coming any one can help me.
